# Totally lost with Mobius Forms v5 on DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am failing to understand if:

1. The contents of the form are emailed out or not.
2. All I can get out and received via email are notifications of a submission.

What I am looking for is where to put a destination email address that will receive the form contents

Thank you

permutated though all the configure this form parameters and do not understand how it works.
I suspect it should email the contents of the form but to what email address... where do you put the receiving email account.

I dont want to send an email to the owner of the site, but to a different email address

Comment: I don't know Mobius Forms actually, only that it is a 2sxc app. The reason why the contents are not sent could be that email is not a secure transmission mode, and therefore it could result with some troubles concerning the GDPR. But hopefully someone from the 2sxc team will answer soon...

Comment: Another thing: You could also ask this in the [Community Forums](https://dnncommunity.org/forums), there are many experts also in 2sxc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When data from a Mobius form is submitted, I expected that the contents would be emailed to the recipient, instead, only an announcement that data was submited is emailed.